# How I could make a Linux OS for a CPU that I designed?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, linux-capabilities

Background information on the architecture: I just designed a set of instructions for a CPU that I'm going to put in an FPGA, but I want to be able to do it compatible with Linux (a simple Linux system) but I just started with this and I do not know much about this, I'm sure Linux can serve in my CPU. I think AVR supports Linux too, but I do not know if this is true but if this is true I think my CPU can also.
My CPU is 16 bits, and it has the following registers:

1. AX
2. BX
3. CX
4. DX
5. EX
6. FX

This can support up to 256 (16-bits registers),  I also only put a few registers because I do not know if it will give me space for the VGA driver in my FPGA, think that 8 registers more could fit in the register file. My FPGA board has a Cyclone IV.
The program counter
or (PC) of my CPU is 16 bits.
My CPU handles data with Pointers (ARP, BRP) that point to two registers and take the value of the registers to the two outputs that can be used to put the values (A, B) of the ALU. To save data in the registers I use two pointers as well (CRP, DRP) with these I point to the registers where the values will be stored, the instructions say if the pointers are going to be used to save a value because otherwise, the value would be saved in two registers by mistake.
I do not know if this information is useful to give you an idea if I'm going to be able to use Linux in my design.
Thank you so much! ☺

Question: Is it possible to port Linux to a 16bit architecture?

Edit: After almost 3 years of gained experience with embedded systems, I see how ignorant this question is. I cannot provide an answer to this question because this question is flagged to not accept answers. But I will try to explain why porting Linux natively to a 16bit CPU is almost impossible.

- Real Linux requires MMU to work, although there is uClinux which requires no MMU. MMU is required to provide userspace programs with their own memory address space without other programs interfering.
- 16bit address space is too limited to even run what is required. As the smaller Linux installations that I've seen need 8MB which is way off the 16bit address space (64 kilobytes).
- Linux kernel needs Binutils and GCC to compile!
- It will be very hacky and tricky to port GCC because GCC was designed to target 32bit architectures.
- I mentioned earlier that it's almost impossible but, you can do emulation and with help of external hardware, you can emulate another architecture. But that's cheating, isn't it?
  http://dmitry.gr/index.php?r=05.Projects&proj=07.%20Linux%20on%208bit
- Finally, if you really want to run Linux on your custom CPU, start with RISCV. It supports GCC and all the required tools, plus RISCV is the future!

If you really want to run an OS in your custom CPU, you can port it to the LCC compiler. Run RTOS. This is a more realistic approach. But still, it is a challenging one.

Comment: Do you have an compiler for your architecture? Even if you have, very likely linux will never will be built in it, because it relyes on some gcc features

Comment: Also if your cpu don't have mmu, linux woldn't work. And there is much more. You better start with a hello world example.

Comment: @AlexHoppus that is not true. Linux runs also on MMU-less CPUs. 16 bit however, it doesn't do :-)

Comment: Real Linux requires an MMU. What runs on MMU-less CPU is not really a Linux, just a pale imitation

Comment: You need to read at least [*Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/) and then look into http://osdev.org/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are out of luck. Linux requires a 32 bit system to run.